# How to create a sorted key-value map that can be serialized by Gin to json?

Tags: json, go, marshalling, encode, go-gin

I'm using Gin to create a REST API. The response I'm trying to create is a key-value json map such as:

```
    "content": {
        "1.4.5.": {
            "id": "1.4.5.",
            "content": "some content",
            "title": "title"
        },
        "1.4.6.": {
            "id": "1.4.6.",
            "content": "another content",
            "title": "another title"
        },
```

The data model that I'm using is:

```
type TopicBundle struct {
  ...
  Content      map[string]Topic `json:"content"`
}
```

And it is correctly serialized to json with:

```
c.JSON(200, topicBundle)
```

Almost.

The map[string]Topic never gets its values in the right order. I create it from a sorted map. But it does not help.

```
    var contentMap = make(map[string]Topic, sm.Len())
    for _, key := range sm.Keys() {
        contentMap[key.(string)] = first(sm.Get(key)).(Topic)
    }
```

At some point this map seems to be recreated and keys change their order a litte bit.
I cannot think of any other alternatives as Gin seems to correctly serialize only this primitive key-value map. The sorted map from github.com/umpc/go-sortedmap is not serialized at all.

So how do I keep the order of keys in this primitive (native?) structure? Or should I write a custom serializer for Gin?

I tried to find the solution on the internet.

Comment: if you want a particular order, use a json list / go slice.

Comment: @erik258 , but how do I get key:value in json? It's a map, not a list. Can a list be serialized to a key:value?

Comment: I have added my custom sorting to my client code (Angular), but I would like to produce sorted map results with my REST API. In Java I use LinkedHashMap for that.

Comment: You need to write application code to marshal in the desired order (about 10 or so lines of code) or find a package that does it for you.

Comment: Even if you may find a hack that works, Golang maps do not preserve the order. As others said, simple solution would be to switch to a slice of key-value pairs that is converted to a JSON list of the same key-value pairs, ordered by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution in my case was to write a wrapper around **sortedmap.SortedMap** and a custom **MarshalJSON** for this wrapper:

```
type TopicBundle struct {
    Content      SortedMapWrapper `json:"content"`
}
type SortedMapWrapper struct {
    topics *sortedmap.SortedMap
}

func (wrapper SortedMapWrapper) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var sb strings.Builder
    var counter = 0
    sb.WriteString("{")
    for _, key := range wrapper.topics.Keys() {
        sb.WriteString("\"")
        sb.WriteString(key.(string))
        sb.WriteString("\":")
        sb.Write(first(json.Marshal(first(wrapper.topics.Get(key)))))
        counter += 1
        if counter < wrapper.topics.Len() {
            sb.WriteString(",")
        }
    }
    sb.WriteString("}")
    return []byte(sb.String()), nil
}
func loadTopic(c *gin.Context) {
    var contentMap = sortedmap.New(1, comparisonFunc)
    contentMap.Insert("val1", Topic{"val1", "val2", "val3"})
    contentMap.Insert("val33", Topic{"val1", "val2", "val3"})
    var topicBundle = TopicBundle{}
    topicBundle.Content = SortedMapWrapper{contentMap}
    c.JSON(200, topicBundle)
}
```

Note that the definition of MarshalJSON should use SortedMapWrapper (**not *SortedMapWrapper**). Otherwise it will not be found.